# how to threshold with a new defined column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I am defining a new column by converting table's start_time and want to filter with respect to this change.

```
select job_name, convert(varchar(10), start_time, 101) as startdate , other_stuff
from table where startdate = '2013-05-08' order by start_time asc
```

but I get an error saying startdate is not a valid column. How can I filter like this? Anyone help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use alias column in where clause...

A workaround for the problem is by using the derived table which do have your select statement rows....

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT job_name, convert(varchar(10), start_time, 101) as startdate , other_stuff
FROM table
) new_table
WHERE startdate = '2013-05-08' ORDER BY start_time ASC
```